# How to find the induced Lie algebra homomorphism

Tags: lie-groups

Consider the quaternions $H=\{1+bi+cj+dk, a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and the norm $\|h\|=\sqrt{h^*h}$, which is a Lie group homomorphism between $H^*$ and $\mathbb R^*$. How can I find the Lie algebra homomorphism induced by the norm?